# Dualizing linear optimization problem with double summation and dependent indices

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have a question about linear optimization in which I have a double summation and I can't find out how I can convert this to it's dual.

This is the problem:
\begin{align}
\min \quad & \sum_{l=1}^M \sum_{m=1}^l p_{ml} x_{ml} \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & \sum_{m=1}^i \sum_{l=i}^M x_{ml} \geq d_i \text{ for all } i=1,\ldots,M \\
& x_{ml} \geq 0 \text{ for all } m=1,\ldots,M, l=1,\ldots,M
\end{align}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is via the Lagrangian:

$$L(x,y) = \sum_{l=1}^M \sum_{m=1}^l p_{ml} x_{ml} + \sum_{i=1}^M y_i (d_i - \sum_{m=1}^i \sum_{l=i}^M x_{ml})$$

Note that
$$\sum_{i=1}^M y_i \sum_{m=1}^i\sum_{l=i}^M x_{ml} = \sum_{i=1}^M \sum_{l=i}^M \sum_{m=1}^i y_i x_{ml} = \sum_{l=1}^M \sum_{i=1}^l \sum_{m=1}^i y_i x_{ml} = \sum_{l=1}^M \sum_{m=1}^l \sum_{i=m}^l y_i x_{ml}$$

So you can separate each $x_{ml}$ in the Lagrangian by writing it as:
$$L(x,y) = \sum_i d_i y_i + \sum_{l=1}^M \sum_{m=1}^l \left( p_{ml} - \sum_{i=m}^l y_i \right) x_{ml} $$

The dual is:

$$\max_{y \geq 0} \min_{x \geq 0} L(x,y) = \max_{y \geq 0} \begin{cases} \sum_i d_i y_i & \text{if } p_{ml} - \sum_{i=m}^l y_i \geq 0 \text{ for all } l=1,\ldots,M, m=1,\ldots,l  \\ -\infty & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
So the dual is:
$$\max_{y\geq 0} \left\{ \sum_i d_i y_i : p_{ml} - \sum_{i=m}^l y_i \geq 0 \text{ for all } l=1,\ldots,M, m=1,\ldots,l \right\}$$

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot! I have another question which is very different from this and also looks to me like something which does not have a dual, can I ask you about this as well?

Comment: @Superizer you can always ask, please mark this question answered and ask it as a new question

Comment: So, I have a totally different problem for which I also have no clue how to compute the dual, it is given by this: [link](https://imgur.com/a/mWFtZ1V)

Comment: @Superizer could you post it as a new question and properly format it via [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: Yeah sure! I will do it now :)

Comment: Hi I posted it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849235/dualizing-linear-optimization-problem-with-difficult-indices-in-summation. I wrote it via mathjax to hopefully make it easier for you as well. Thanks in advance!