# Dualizing linear optimization problem with difficult indices in summation

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have a question about linear optimization in which I have a double summation and I can't find out how I can convert this to it's dual.

This is the problem$:\\$

Maximize $p$

Subject to:

$\sum_{i \in I: \; a_i = i} x_i \leq M + \sum_{i \in I: \; b_i = i} m_i x_i$ for all $i=1,...,K$

$p + \sum_{i \in I: \; a_i = i} x_i \leq \sum_{i \in I: \; b_i = i} m_i x_i$ for all $i=K+1,...,L$

$d_i \geq x_i \geq 0$ for all $i=1,...,L\\ \\$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you appreciate my answer?

Comment: yes of course! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is via the Lagrangian:
$$L(p,x,y,z) = p + \sum_{i=1}^K y_i\left(M+\sum_{i\in I : b_i=i} m_i x_i - \sum_{i\in I : a_i=i} x_i\right)+ \sum_{i=K+1}^L y_i\left(\sum_{i\in I : b_i=i} m_i x_i - p - \sum_{i\in I : a_i=i} x_i \right) + \sum_{i=1}^L z_i\left(d_i-x_i\right) $$

Note that:
$$L(p,x,y,z) = \sum_{i=1}^K My_i + \sum_{i=1}^L z_i d_i + \left(1-\sum_{i=K+1}^L y_i \right) p + \sum_{i=1}^L c_i(y) x_i $$
where $c_i(y,z) = y_i m_i 1_{b_i=i}-y_i1_{a_i=i}-z_i$. The expression $1_{a_i=i}$ takes the value $1$ if $a_i=i$, $0$ otherwise.

The dual is:
$$\min_{y,z} \max_{x \geq 0,p} L(p,x,y,z) = \min_{y,z} \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^K My_i + \sum_{i=1}^L z_i d_i : 1-\sum_{i=K+1}^L y_i = 0, c_i(y,z)\leq0, i=1,\ldots,L \right\} $$